# How to send message using Gmail API with PHP YII2 Google API Client?

Tags: php, yii2, gmail-api

How to send a message using Gmail API with PHP YII2 Google API Client?

I have tried to send the E-mail and the E-mail has been triggered, but the same E-mail is bouncing back to me.

```
  $mail = new PHPMailer();
            $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
            $subject = $subject;
            $msg = $message;
            $fromadd = $email;
            $fname = $email;
            $mail->From = $fromadd;
            $mail->FromName = $fname;
            /* $mail->AddAddress($toaddr); */
            foreach ($addr as $ad) {
                $mail->AddAddress(trim($ad));
            }
            foreach ($ccaddr as $add) {
                $mail->AddCC(trim($add));
            }
            $mail->AddReplyTo($fromadd, $fname);
            $mail->Subject = $subject;
            $mail->Body = $msg;
            foreach ($path as $key => $value) {
                $mail->AddAttachment($path[$key], $name[$key]);
            }

            $mail->IsHTML(true);
            $mail->preSend();
            $mime = $mail->getSentMIMEMessage();
```

Comment: The code that you've provided has nothing to do with YII2 or Google's API client. Are you asking for someone to rewrite your code to use Google's API?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the gmail api, this php mailer if want to use it and send email from your gmail, you have to configure mailer and initiate it with the smtp values that are associated with your gmail account